# How do I make it cross dissolve between 2 views when rotating to portrait?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, screen-rotation

I have a separate landscape view of a clock i've made and I want this to cross dissolve in when the phone is rotated to landscape, and then cross dissolve back when it returns to portrait, but when I've tried this in different ways, i've been having problems.

Suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add your two separate views as subviews of your view controllers main view.

Implement:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

in your view controller, adding code like this to handle the cross dissolve:

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"cross dissovle" context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0f];
self.firstView.alpha = 0.0f;
self.secondView.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Obviously you'll need to implement the other case and put some logic around it, but that is left as an exercise for the reader ;-).